# PySCIPOpt/SCIP - Branching/Separation with fractional variable

Tags: python-3.x, discrete-mathematics, scip

I began using PySCIPOpt/SCIP for a Coursera course on discrete optimization. I'd need to implement a simple separation from a fractional variable and wonder how to do it. Online SCIP literature does not provide relevant example. 
Any Python example for me to get inspired for my assignment?

Thank you for the answer. Indeed I spent some hours reading SCIP documentation and I have trouble interfacing SCIp methods in Python.
I have been able to implement in Python a simple constraint handler to add first-type cuts and I'd like to add a separator to add second-type cuts.
The latter cuts are typically x = 0 or 1 cuts based on fractional x values and I stumble more with syntax - addCut() - and using generic methods than the process itself.
A Python example, a bit more involved than tsp.py, would greatly help me.

Comment: In general, posting your homework questions from paid online programming courses on Stackoverflow is going to garner down votes then negative reputation.  You haven't done enough due diligence to show us what you tried.  Your professor worked hard to create a question that had no easy answer online to create a learning opportunity for you to learn to problem solve, and if we were to do your work for you here then it really defeats the purpose, since it's clear you've put in almost zero effort.

Comment: Hi Eric, I reckon question was too general... I am trying to learn to use PyScipopt to the full extent and generated MIP TSP and VRP models so far using constraint handlers. My failed attempts at making use of separators - process, syntax - led me to think I was not using Python SCIP interface properly.

Comment: To help you get upvotes next time when asking on stackoverflow, include an: http://sscce.org The post has to convince readers that you tried everything you could to solve your own problem. See https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried  One issue with posting homework like this, is that it's not a "real work problem".  It's an artificial fake-problem that's been made hard on purpose to cause learning. We have the ability and energy to do your homework for you, we just choose not to.  Asking good questions isn't easy, it takes some skill.  See: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite broad. I try to give some hints on where to look for an answer:

- [general information on separators in SCIP](http://scip.zib.de/doc-5.0.1/html/SEPA.php)
- [difference between constraint handlers and separators](http://scip.zib.de/doc-5.0.1/html/FAQ.php#conshdlrvsseparator)
- [Python example on a separator implemented as constraint handler to solve the Traveling Salesman Problem](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt/blob/master/tests/test_tsp.py)

I can try to answer your question more precisely, if you explain your application/problem in more detail.

Comment: @PC_AD, why do you edit *my answer* instead of *your question*? This is not how SO works.